# Automapper foces subobjects to be mapped

Tags: c#, automapper-3

I am trying to map a response object from webservice to a Class in my project. I thought the Automapper will map even the sub objects automatically, it does not unless and until is forcefully set for the member. Why should i do this ?

`Mapper.CreateMap<GetIfpQuoteResponse.Quote, QuoteWSModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.CarrierRate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Carriers))
.ForMember(dest => dest.DroppedCarriers, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DroppedRates))
.ForMember(dest => dest.MemberPlans, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MemberPlans));`

Why Wont the automapper map my su bobjects when i mention the class mapping like this

`Mapper.CreateMap<GetIfpQuoteResponse.Quote, QuoteWSModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<GetIfpQuoteResponse.Quote.Carrier, CarrierRateModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<GetIfpQuoteResponse.Quote.DroppedCarrier, DroppedCarrierModel>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoMapper only map **top level** object.

If your class is built in the following way it will not work:

```
Class A
{
  B b;
}

Class B
{

}
```

Class A will not know how to map property B inside class A.

To do this you will need to create a Profile class.

[Auto Mapper tutorial](https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/2/Pages/1)